# Accessing function from class and from instance of this class

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is this code:

```
class B:
    def f(self):
        pass

print(B.f) # <function B.f at 0xb711977c>
print(B().f) # <bound method B.f of <__main__.B object at 0xb71774cc>>
```

How does interpreter know that when function `f` is accessed from class object then normal function is returned but when this function is accessed from class instance then bound method is returned? I read that there is a `__get__` function which is used to bind objects with functions but how this works internally for class and class instance?

Comment: The mechanism is called "descriptors": http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html. It's somewhat of a gnarly implementation detail though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions are implemented as [descriptors](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html). To quote the documentation:

> In general, a descriptor is an object attribute with “binding behavior”, one whose attribute access has been overridden by methods in the descriptor protocol. Those methods are `__get__()`, `__set__()`, and `__delete__()`. If any of those methods are defined for an object, it is said to be a descriptor.

The idea is that the `__get__` method allows to identify *how* the attribute was fetched. Consider this simple example:

```
>>> class Descriptor(object):
...     def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
...         print '__get__(%r, %r)' % (obj, type)
...
>>> class A(object):
...     desc = Descriptor()
...
>>> A.desc
__get__(None, <class '__main__.A'>)
>>> A().desc
__get__(<__main__.A object at 0x020F5B50>, <class '__main__.A'>)
```

As you can see, and as described in the [`__get__` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__), the `obj` parameter allow to distinguish attribute access through class or instance. **The same mechanism can be used by Python's internal to return either a bound or unbound method when accessing a function attribute.**

In practice:

```
>>> class A:
...     def f(self):
...             pass
...
>>> A.f.__get__(None, A)
<unbound method A.f>
>>> A.f.__get__(A(), A)
<bound method A.f of <__main__.A instance at 0x022082D8>>
```

This is all Python 2.x examples, but as far as I know, things work the same for Python 3.x except that unbound methods are regular functions.